# Symfony-Doctrine : join a table with a view after persisting entity

Tags: symfony, view, doctrine-orm, orm, entity

In my database, I have a table `T` and a view `V`.
The view has some columns of my table and other data (from other tables).

In Symfony, I declared my view as a read-only Entity.

```
/**
  * @ORM\Table(name="V")
  * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true, repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\Repository\VRepository")
  */
class V
{
```

In my `T` entity, I did a Join :

```
/**
  * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="V")
  * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="T_id", referencedColumnName="V_id")
  */
 private $view;
```

And I added just the getter :

```
/**
 * Get view
 *
 * @return \AppBundle\Entity\V
 */
public function getView()
{
     return $this->view;
}
```

Everything is working well when I want to read and show data.

**But I have a problem after persisting a new `T` entity.**
Symfony seems to lost posted data of my form when I create a new `T` entity (`editAction()` works perfectly).

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO T (T_id, T_name, updated_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params [null, null, "2017-09-01 15:30:41"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Field 'T_id' cannot be empty (null)
```

When I remove ORM annotations of the `$view` property, it creates correctly my new record `T` in the database.

I think the problem is due to the fact that the `V` entity (the record in my SQL view) will exist just after the creation of `T`. And when I persist/flush data in Symfony, `V` doesn't exist yet. They are "created" at the same time.

I tried to add Doctrine `@HasLifecycleCallbacks` on my `T` entity and the `@PostPersist` event on the `getView()` method but it doesn't change anything...

Any idea to differ the Join after the creation of the entity ?

I know it's not conventional to use views as entities with Symfony but I haven't other choice.

Comment: Show suitable code sample. How do you assign `V` to `T` if it doesn't exist yet and you cannot create its instance since it's read only?

Comment: Please add controller and form type

Comment: @Jakub Matczak : `V` is just a view which selects data from `T` table and other tables. I don't need to create an instance of `V`, the One-to-One relation does that.

Comment: From OOP point of view if doesn't matter if it's a view or not. You said that `V` will exist after  creation of `T`, so it does not exist yet. That's why I asked you to provide code sample, to see how you solved it in your code.

Comment: Actually, `V` exists in the same time than `T` because `V = T` with some other data. It is just a SQL request that selects `T` id, `T` name, etc... If `T` doesn't exist then `V` doesn't exist and once `T` is created, `V` exists. It was a way of speaking... I don't know how to explain it to you in a different way. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just checked, it **works fine with [Bidirectional One-To-One relation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional)**

In my case tables are defined like:

```
create table T (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(100), primary key (id));
create view V as select id as entity, name, '123' as number from T;
```

Annotations in T:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="T")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class T
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var V
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="V", mappedBy="entity")
     */
    private $view;
```

Annotations in V:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="V")
 * @ORM\Entity(readOnly=true)
 */
class V
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="number", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $number;

    /**
     * @var T
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="T", inversedBy="view")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="entity", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $entity;
```

And a test snippet to prove that it saves, updates and reads fine:

```
public function testCRUD()
{
    /** @var EntityManager $manager */
    $manager = $this->client->getContainer()->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');

    $t = new T();
    $t->setName('Me');

    $manager->persist($t);
    $manager->flush();

    $t->setName('He');
    $manager->flush();

    $manager->clear();
    /** @var T $t */
    $t = $manager->find(T::class, $t->getId());
    $this->assertEquals('He', $t->getView()->getName());
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine but using a bidirectional relation slows my interface too much. It exceeds my max-execution time when I listed all records (more than 870 of T records).
When I use an unidirectional relation, the execution is very fast.

Comment: I can paginate records on some pages (so the display works fine) but, in my Ajax request for some search fields, all the records are displayed at the same time and it crashes.

Comment: Hm.. usually when you make a query - doctrine does not load all relations, until you request them. How do you make that failing query? Could you post the code?

Comment: I do a simple EntityType in my form that loads all the 870 `T` records in a choice list field enhanced with Select2 js. I managed to paginate the results of Select2 ajax request after doing a search but it crashes with the load of 870 records when the form is displayed... 
`$builder->add('entity', EntityType::class, array(
 'class'   => 'AppBundle:T',
 'choice_label' => 'id'
))`

Comment: 870 records in drop-down select is a lot:) You can improve speed and stability in 2 places: 1)in your form - add simple Choice type and feed it with array of strings (instead of array of entities) 2)while fetching data you could write a custom query on dql and fetch data as array, instead of entities.

Comment: I had the same idea but I have dependent dropdown and it's easier for me to keep entities. I just limited the number of results of my EntityType to 25 and it seems to work very well now with Select2 js.
So, I think it's OK now, I will continue to do some tests. Thank you very much for your help ! I kept the bidirectional relation as you wrote.

Comment: You are welcome. Most probably slow part of system is EntityType field. You could still work with entities, but convert them to array of strings before putting into form field.

Comment: You were right, finally I added a simple ChoiceType field with an array of `T` ids. I use my form as a service to get the EntityManager in the constructor for my dependent dropdown. Thanks !

Comment: Also property $entity should not be typed with the entity's class or you will get an error

Answer (score 0):

Based on the @Maksym Moskvychev answer : Prefer a bidirectional One-to-One relation.

`T` Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="V", mappedBy="entity")
 */
 private $view;
```

`V` Entity :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="T", inversedBy="view")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="V_id", referencedColumnName="T_id")
 */
 private $entity;
```

> > Fix the loss of data after posting the `addAction()` form (new `T` instance).

In the form where I list all `T` records :

```
$builder->add('entity', EntityType::class, array(
    'class'         => 'AppBundle:T',
    'choice_label'  => 'id',
    'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
            ->orderBy('t.name', 'ASC')
            ->setMaxResults(25);    // limit the number of results to prevent crash
    }
))
```

> > Fix the too consuming resources problem (show 25 entities instead of 870+).

Ajax request :

```
$(".select2").select2({
    ajax: {
        type        : "GET",
        url         : "{{ path('search_select') }}",
        dataType    : 'json',
        delay       : 250,
        cache       : true,
        data        : function (params) {
            return {
                q       : params.term, // search term
                page    : params.page || 1
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Response for Select2 :

```
$kwd    = $request->query->get('q');    // GET parameters
$page   = $request->query->get('page');

$limit = 25;
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;

$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$repository = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:V');

$qb = $repository->createQueryBuilder('v');
$where = $qb->expr()->orX(
    $qb->expr()->like('v.name', ':kwd'),
    $qb->expr()->like('v.code', ':kwd')
);
$qb->where($where);

// get the DQL for counting total number of results
$dql = $qb->getDQL();

$results = $qb->orderBy('m.code', 'ASC')
    ->setFirstResult($offset)
    ->setMaxResults($limit)
    ->setParameter('kwd', '%'.$kwd.'%')
    ->getQuery()->getResult();

// count total number of results
$qc = $em->createQuery($dql)->setParameter('kwd', '%'.$kwd.'%');
$count = count($qc->getResult());

// determine if they are more results or not
$endCount = $offset + $limit;
$morePages = $count > $endCount;

$items = array();
foreach ($results as $r) {    
    $items[] = array(
        'id'    => $r->getCode(),
        'text'  => $r->getName()
    );
}

$response = (object) array(
    "results"    => $items,
    "pagination" => array(
        "more" => $morePages
    )
);

if (!empty($results))
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
```